# Incompatibility between french babel and KOMA-Script letter class?

Tags: koma-script, letters, babel-french

I want to compile a letter in French using KOMAScript (2018/03/30 v3.25) and choosing 'french' as an option for babel. When I am running the following minimal example using TeXLive 2018 on a Mac,

```
\documentclass[parskip=full+]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Destinataire}
\opening{Bonjour,}
blablabla
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error messages:

> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
>
> -29- ***Attention*** : le moteur TeX en utilisation avec des fontes CM
>
> (comme dans ce format TeX) est insuffisant pour la cÈsure
>
> des mots accentuÈs (comme en franÁais).
>
> -52- Erreur : e-french package ne fonctionne pas avec une classe de document si minimaliste, dÈsolÈ !
>
> ) ) ) )
>
> (\end occurred when \ifx on line 459 was incomplete)
>
> (\end occurred when \ifx on line 459 was incomplete)
>
> No pages of output.

Is there any known incompatibility between the french babel option and scrlttr2 and what needs to be done to use scrlttr2 with the french option ? I don't have any issues using english or german as options.

Comment: The example compiles fine (i.e. without error) for me, if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I can even get rid of the only warning (only if you use pdfLaTeX, with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX that should not be necessary). The output looks fine. Is your system up to date (your KOMA script is recent, but maybe other packages are outdated), i.e. did you check for updates?

Comment: The `KOMA-Script` manual states (p. 499): “If you use the `babel` package to switch to `french`, problems can occasionally occur. With `babel`, however, you can usually deactivate changes to a language in a targeted manner.” I’m not sure if this helps.

Comment: looks as if your system is finding e-french, instead of french. Do you have a full texlive? Is it up-to-date?

Comment: perhaps try option `frenchb` in place of `french` and report if it changes something.

Answer (score 2):

Error messages like yours often happened, when `e-french` has been used, because `e-french` never was compatible with KOMA-Script and several other non-standard classes. But for several versions of `babel` it does not use any code of `e-french` and the `babel-french` manual even notes, that `french.cfg` of `e-french` is incompatible with `babel-french`. So if you still have an old installation of `e-french` or an old `french.cfg` of `e-french` you should remove them.

And maybe you should update your TeX Live installation. With an up-to-date KOMA-Script 3.26b and `babel` 3.27 (last available version for TeX Live 2018) with `french.ldf` 3.5d or with `babel` 3.29 (current release on CTAN or in TeX Live 2019) and `french.ldf` 3.5e no such error occurs.

With `pdflatex` their is only a warning message:

> ```
> Package french.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
> (french.ldf)                Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble
> (french.ldf)                of your document; reported on input line 3.
> ```

which can be avoided by adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

or by using `lualatex` or `xelatex`.